# What do these metaphors about hardship in "The Amazing Adventures of Kavalier & Clay" mean?

Tags: meaning, amazing-adventures-kavalier-clay, michael-chabon

I have been racking my brain with the meaning of three expressions:

taut-jawed men - does it mean that they are stern looking, that their facial expression is tight and tense?

brick-lipped, hard-heeled women - same sense as number 1, I mean that they are with pursed lips or are they wearing some kind of reddish lipstick?

the hard-heeled part - does it mean that their heels are rough, in the sense that they are hurrying, hard-working women, etc., hence their cracked heels though we can't know that just from looking at them on the street.
Is it more like they are stomping so hard because they are brusque?

Just to be on the safe side and provide some context, here is the whole sentence:

> "He walked along Eighth Street, over to Christopher, then to the river, threading his way like a pickpocket through the crowds just off the ferryboats from New Jersey: taut-jawed men in stiff hats and suits and obsidian shoes, newspapers pinned under their arms; brusque, brick-lipped, hard-heeled women in floral dresses."
>   <sub>*The Amazing Adventures of Kavalier & Clay*, by Michael Chabon ([page 173](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=3T61gEg6WhwC&pg=PA173&lpg=PA173&dq=%22He+walked+along+Eighth+Street,+over+to+Christopher,+then+to+the+river,+threading+his+way+like+a+pickpocket+through+the+crowds+just+off+the+ferryboats+from+New+Jersey:+taut-jawed+men+in+stiff+hats+and+suits+and+obsidian+shoes,+newspapers+pinned+under+their+arms;+brusque,+brick-lipped,+hard-heeled+women+in+floral+dresses.%22&source=bl&ots=k61ID1oMMN&sig=qYnVQofkm8VGlZek4HsYHZsku-k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyg8no78XWAhUGaRQKHQW3AVoQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22He%20walked%20along%20Eighth%20Street%22&f=false))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be more appropriate to say "metaphors of hardness" as opposed to "metaphors of hardship" and this will readily be borne out in their context in the extract .
Prior to the extract Joe has been to make enquiries at the German Consulate about exit visas for his family (trapped and experiencing hardship through discrimination and disadvantage)  in Nazi occupied Prague and leaving dissapointed ( yet again ) he is in a pessimistic frame of mind as he disembarks from the subway car.
The language of the extract serves mirror his unspoken thoughts of our protagonist concerning the unfeeling inflexible, stone cold, unsympathetic attitudes of bureacracy to his vulnerable entrapped family.Metaphors of hardness abound with "taut-jawed"  "stiff" hatted and suited  men with "obsidian shoes"  and "brick lipped hard heeled women" clothed in the paradoxically contrasting softness of "floral dresses".

Regarding your questions : yes the "taut-jawed" men are indeed tense and therefore this  stiffness of jaw manifest as a corresponding severe facial appearance, regarding the "brick lipped"  women : brick is a double metaphor  connoting  both lipstick ( a shade of red )  and unnatural hardness, additonally these women  are "hard heeled" and to emphasise their hardness by way of contrast they wear 'floral dresses" .